# Flutter Packages - Migration Android V2 Error

Tags: flutter, dart, migration

I have an error about migration android version

I follow the step by this document https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

But I do not found solution my problems because These files are not available in the package

[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPa4F.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXnGi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2qPj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIo2H.png)

please

Hello dear,

I have an error about migration android version

I follow the step by this document https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

But I do not found solution my problems because These files are not available in the package

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a corrupted `android` directory. I can tell from the screenshot you posted that `android` directory is missing a lot of file (gradle, androidManifest, res.. etc).

If this a new project please regenerate a new project with this command `flutter create [your_project_name]`